# beforeDestroy vue dynamic component

Tags: vue.js

How could I add an alert message before switch the component? (`beforeDestroy` does not work until the path is changed...)

```
<template>
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
  </keep-alive>
</template>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you already discovered, when you keep a component alive, it doesn't throw "`beforeDestroy`" and "`created`" as normal components, since its being kept alive.

Therefore, Vue has defined other lifecycle methods for this purpose:

- [`activated`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated) - This gets called when `keep-alive` loads the component
- [`deactivated`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#deactivated) - This gets called when `<keep-alive>` unloads the component

You use them like this:

```
export default {
    created() {
        console.log('created');
    },
    activated() {
        console.log('activated');
    },
    deactivated() {
        console.log('deactivated');
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        console.log('beforeDestroy');
    },
}
```